# UIImages: should I use stored or computed properties?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiimage

I haven't thought about it much until today. Basically I'm in a situation in which I have the same UIImage appear multiple times in my `ViewController`s, and I'm not sure what the impact is.

```swift
class MyObjectA{
    private(set) var myName: String
    var myImage: UIImage? { UIImage(named: myName) }  //as computed property
}

class MyObjectB{
    private(set) var myName: String
    private(set) var myImage: UIImage?  //as stored property

    init(myName: String){
        self.myName = myName
        self.myImage = UIImage(named: myName)
    }
}
```

Consider a TableView, where each cell corresponds to an object. Is it bad having an image constantly being instantiated with `myimageview.image = UIImage(named: myobject.imagename)` versus just instantiating once and referencing it with `myimageview.image = myobect.image` ? Or does Swift do some super magic where it optimizes it under the hood, knowing that image was already loaded once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS has an `UIImage` cache, so calling `UIImage(named: myobject.imagename)` multiple times for the same image is perfectly fine.

[The documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init)

> Use the `init(named:in:compatibleWith:)` method (or the `init(named:)`
> method) to create an image from an image asset or image file located
> in your app’s main bundle (or some other known bundle). Because these
> methods **cache the image data automatically**, they’re especially
> recommended for images that you use frequently.

Comment: Using `image(named:)` is a file system call. There will be a little overhead to fetch the cached image. For most situations the difference wouldn't be enough to matter, but if you were writing code to parse every pixel in an image, say, then the computed property approach would be slower.

Comment: @DuncanC Fair point.  However to parse pixels in a `UIImage`, you'd convert it once to a CIImage and work with that.  Yes, I know it was just an example :-)

Comment: The thing about computed properties is that it hides things like that from the consuming developer. From the declaration it looks like an instance var unless you’re paying close attention. I’m not sure I’d use a computed variable for something that did a file system call. For that matter, doesn’t it use copy semantics and give you a unique copy each time you ask for it? I’ll have to experiment with that.

Comment: Thanks! So essentially, because iOS caches UIImages, it's really ok to use computed properties for it, but it seems that stored properties are still technically more efficient. Thanks for the valuable info!!

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind using a computed property or a stored one is when the value of the property being changed or not with time ,so given ex.1

```
class MyObjectA{
    private(set) var myName: String
    var myImage: UIImage? { UIImage(named: myName) }  //as computed property
```

So if `myName` changes with time then you need to make `myImage` a computed property to always get the latest updated image , but if `myName` is being set only once then you need to make it a stored property